# Unable to connect to MongoDB container replica set, but able to connect to stand-alone instance

Tags: mongodb, docker

## Background

I'm trying to create a `docker-compose.yml` to initiate a MongoDB replica set (with 3 instances). Things look good and the replica set can be initiated successfully (`rs.initiate(config)`).

## Connect to stand-alone instance from Host

On the same host, I tried to `mongosh` into it.

The following line works. It connects to a stand-alone instance.

```bash
# On Host
$ mongosh localhost:3001
...
Connecting to:          mongodb://localhost:3001/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.6
...
rs0 [direct: primary] test> rs.status()
{
  set: 'rs0',
  ...
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'mongo1:27017',
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      ...
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'mongo2:27017',
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      ...
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'mongo3:27017',
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      ...
    },
  ],
  ok: 1,
  ...
}
```

## Connect to replica set from within a MongoDB container

If I go into the container shell and try to connect to replica set, it works.

```bash
# On Host
$ docker compose exec -it mongo1 bash

# mongo1 container
$ mongosh mongodb://mongo1,mongo2,mongo3?replicaSet=rs0
... success
rs0 [primary] test>
```

## Connect to replica set from Host

If I try to connect to replica set from Host, it fails. Not just via. `mongosh` but also drivers like `pymongo` and `mongodb` for NodeJS.

The following commands all failed:

```bash
# On Host, all fails
$ mongosh mongodb://localhost:3001?replicaSet=rs0
$ mongosh mongodb://localhost:3001,localhost:3002,localhost:3003?replicaSet=rs0
$ mongosh "mongodb://localhost:3001,localhost:3002,localhost:3003?replicaSet=rs0&authSource=admin"

# All yields the same error:
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 2000 ms
```

## Am I missing something?

I think this is related to network binding issues. I have specified `--bind_ip_all` when starting the `mongod`. It works for connecting to a stand-alone instance, but not the replica set.

## The Code to reproduce

Just `docker compose up`. After it's ready, retry the commands above.

- `docker-compose.yml`: https://pastebin.com/mTYgffna
- `rs-init.sh`: https://pastebin.com/JLLUTAeC

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of sure I had this problem before. I did the same thing exactly (created replica set using Docker on my computer) and I faced issues connecting to the replica set.

The thing I did was **modifying** `/etc/hosts` and appending these lines:

```
127.0.0.1 mongo_replica_1
127.0.0.1 mongo_replica_2
127.0.0.1 mongo_replica_3
```

**Notice!: I called it `mongo_replica_x` but you should change to `mongox` (`mongo1` for example).**

Then I could successfully connect.

---

If this does not help, I share with you hereby my `docker-compose.yaml` file and the `rs-init.sh` file:

**Docker Compose**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    mongo_launcher:
        container_name: mongo_launcher
        image: mongo:6.0.10
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - ./docker/scripts/mongo-setup.sh:/scripts/mongo-setup.sh
        entrypoint: ['sh', '/scripts/mongo-setup.sh']
    mongo_replica_1:
        container_name: mongo_replica_1
        image: mongo:6.0.10
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27017',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
    mongo_replica_2:
        container_name: mongo_replica_2
        image: mongo:6.0.10
        ports:
            - 27018:27018
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27018',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
    mongo_replica_3:
        container_name: mongo_replica_3
        image: mongo:6.0.10
        ports:
            - 27019:27019
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27019',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
```

**rs-init.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB_REPLICA_1=mongo_replica_1
MONGODB_REPLICA_2=mongo_replica_2
MONGODB_REPLICA_3=mongo_replica_3

echo "************ [ Waiting for startup ] **************" ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}

until mongosh --host ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017 --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())"; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo "************ [ Startup completed ] **************" ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}

mongosh --host ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017 <<EOF
var configuration = {
    "_id": "dbrs",
    "protocolVersion": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017",
            "priority": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_2}:27018",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_3}:27019",
            "priority": 1
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "chainingAllowed": true
    }
};
rs.initiate(configuration);
rs.secondaryOk();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
EOF
```